# What are the powers of the Fated people, places, and objects?

Tags: caraval

All the people, places, and objects depicted in the Deck of Destiny have certain powers. Some of them are shown over the course of the book *Finale*: we know the powers of the Poisoner, the Prince of Hearts, the Assassin, the Fallen Star, Mistress Luck, Jester Mad, Priestess, Priestess, the Lady Prisoner, and the Apothic; the Map of All, the Aracle, Her Majesty's Gown, the Bleeding Throne, and the Reverie Key; and the Menagerie, the Vanished Market, and the Immortal Library.

However, that still leaves a large number of Fated things listed in the appendix, and well as some that appear in the text but use their powers in ambiguous ways. What powers do they have?

Comment: I've got to get back to that series one of these days...